# Curl two web pages alternatively and sequentially

Tags: macos, curl, terminal

I'm trying to curl two web pages alternatively and sequentially.

Let's call them URL-A and URL-B. I need to create a string that allows me to parse these websites with the following pattern URL-A1;URL-B1;URL-A2;URL-B2;URL-A3 and so on.

What I've tried is:

```
curl "http://url.com?i=[001-10]&TOT=0" -o "#1.html" “http://urlB.php?i=[001-10]&TOT=0"  -o "#1.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
curl "http://urlA.com?i=[001-10]&TOT=0" -o xxx; \
curl "http://urlB.com?i=[001-10]&TOT=0" -o yyy"
```

Notice the `;` it will help to run the commands sequentially